# Inequality statement in an ordered field.

Tags: real-analysis

Let $F$ be an ordered field. For all $x \in F$ such that $x < z$, then $x < y$. Does that mean $y \geq z$?

If so, what is the simplest way to prove this. If not, counterexample?

Comment: I believe I am stupid and this is easy. All I have to do is say if $y < z$ then $y < y$ cannot hold

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved. If $y<z$ then $y < y$ cannot hold. so $y \geq z$.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do this easily by contradiction. Let $F$ be an ordered field where for all $x\in F$ such that $x<z$, then $x<y$. Further suppose that $y < z$. By hypothesis, this also means $y<y$, which is a contradiction.